# Can I not sending notification to assignee and approver when I create merge request?

Tags: gitlab

When I create merge request, it will send email to the approver automatically.
May I close it and not send them a email each time?

// I am a junior programmer and always change my code and create MR in gitlab.
I think it is too noisy for them. :C //

Answer (score 0):

You should leave closing and merging process to your mentor i.e. to the one who reviews your code and approves/disaproves changes.